Blob tirggered Azure function - Blob cannot be binded to the first azure function argument in Azure environment
I want to create a simple Azure function which is triggered on a blob upload.
The function works correctly as expected when I run it locally.
The problem is that when I publish the code with Visual Studio 2022 publish option, I get exception and the function is not executed at all. As far as I understood, the problem is that the "Stream" argument of the function cannot be binded for some strange reason.
This is the exception I get:

Error converting 1 input parameters for Function 'BlobTriggeredFunction': Cannot convert input parameter 'stream' to type 'System.IO.Stream' from type 'Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Grpc.Messages.GrpcModelBindingData'. Error:System.FormatException: Settings must be of the form "name=value".
at Azure.Storage.StorageConnectionString.<>c.b__67_0(String err)
at Azure.Storage.StorageConnectionString.ParseStringIntoSettings(String connectionString, Action1 error) at Azure.Storage.StorageConnectionString.ParseCore(String connectionString, StorageConnectionString& accountInformation, Action1 error)
at Azure.Storage.StorageConnectionString.Parse(String connectionString)
at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobServiceClient..ctor(String connectionString, BlobClientOptions options)
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.BlobStorageBindingOptions.CreateClient() in D:\a_work\1\s\extensions\Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs\src\Config\BlobStorageBindingOptions.cs:line 35
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.BlobStorageConverter.CreateBlobContainerClient(String connectionName, String containerName) in D:\a_work\1\s\extensions\Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs\src\BlobStorageConverter.cs:line 253
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.BlobStorageConverter.ConvertModelBindingDataAsync(Type targetType, BlobBindingData blobData) in D:\a_work\1\s\extensions\Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs\src\BlobStorageConverter.cs:line 118
at Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.BlobStorageConverter.ConvertFromBindingDataAsync(ConverterContext context, ModelBindingData modelBindingData) in D:\a_work\1\s\extensions\Worker.Extensions.Storage.Blobs\src\BlobStorageConverter.cs:line 63

This is the function code:

public class BlobTriggeredFunction(ILogger<BlobTriggeredFunction> logger)
{
    [Function(nameof(BlobTriggeredFunction))]
    public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("email-attachments/{name}", Connection = "BlobStorageConnectionString")] Stream stream, string name)
    {
        using var blobStreamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var content = await blobStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} \n Data: {content}");
    }
}

This is the setup in Program.cs:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("host.json");
        if (hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            config.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json");
            config.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
        }
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

secrets.json:
{
  "BlobStorageConnectionString": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "BlobStorageConnectionString:blob": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/",
  "BlobStorageConnectionString:queue": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.queue.core.windows.net/"
}

I tried changing "Stream" argument to byte[] or string, but none of that helped.
I don't expect that the problem is in the connection string, because the function is triggered when I upload a blob, but it cannot be processed.
The worst problem is that it happens only in Azure environment when I publish the code. It works fine in the local environment.

Is this .NET8 Isolated Azure function?

Yes. It is a dotnet core 8 isolated Azure function.

local.settings.json is only used in the local environment in the debug build. Also, local.settings.json is not copied to publish output and it doesn't exist when an application is deployed to the Azure portal.

The problem was that I didn't add environment variables in Program.cs.
Environment variables are used in the Azure portal
.ConfigureAppConfiguration( ( hostContext, config ) =>
{
    config.AddJsonFile( "host.json" );

    if (hostContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("local.settings.json");
        config.AddUserSecrets<ArchiveManagerFunction>(optional: true, reloadOnChange: false);
    }

    config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
} )

So the solution to my problem was in this line of the code:
config.AddEnvironmentVariables();


I have created a sample Blob Trigger Azure Function and could run the deployed Azure function in Portal.
Code Snippet:

Function.cs:

public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

[Function(nameof(Function1))]
public async Task Run([BlobTrigger("sampleitems/{name}", Connection = "storageconnection")] Stream stream, string name)
{
    using var blobStreamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
    var content = await blobStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    _logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} \n Data: {content}");
}

If the "StorageAccountConnectionString" is defined as a user secret in secrets.json, then you need to add user secrets into your program.cs.
.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config => { config.AddUserSecrets<YourFunctionName>(optional: true, reloadOnChange: false); })

Program.cs:
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration( config =>
    {
        config.AddUserSecrets<Function1>(optional: true, reloadOnChange: false);
    })
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();


Add the connection string as an environment variable in Azure function App=>Settings=>Environment Variables=>New Application Setting.

Deployed the Blob Trigger function to Azure.


Portal:

Able to run the function in the portal successfully:


References:

GitHub Issue1

GitHub Issue2



User secrets should only be used in the local environment and debug build. Environment variables are used in the release build and when an app is deployed to the Azure portal.

I have no idea why environment variables are included by default in your case, and not in my case.
